# How many paths are there from A to B?

Tags: combinatorics

How many paths are there from A to B?

[image]

8 is wrong answer.

Comment: Although this is a very small example, in general, it might be helpful (and faster) to work backwards, i.e. from B to A in any crossing, write down the number of paths from the crossing to $B$.

Comment: @Tomas Why is it, in general, faster to work backwards? If all the arrows were reversed and we wanted to count the paths from $B$ to $A$, would it then be faster to work from $A$ to $B$? I have a hard time seeing how it makes any difference?

Comment: Yes it would. If rigorously count all paths from $A$ to $B$, you will notice that you will count certain path sections several times, which you avoid by working backwards. The difference, however, is tiny with such a small network. It becomes clear if you try it with a larger example.

Comment: For instance, at some point, you will have to count the paths beginning with the upper two arrows and at some other point you will count the paths beginning with the lower arrow, the ones which goes up from there and then the one to the right. Both will leave you at the same node and you have to count the number of paths from this node onewards twice. Working backwards, you would only do this once, write down the number, and then use it again whenever you landed on that node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each node (starting from $B$) yo can write down the number of ways from there to $B$.
Then whenever you find a node where the path counts from *all* its successors are known, you know that the path count from that node is the sum over the successors.

This way you finally arrive at $A$ and should find a value of $5$ (the top successor has $2$, the bottom has $3$).

Comment: Why is that better than starting from $A$ and counting the number of paths from $A$ to a node $X$ by adding the path counts for the immediate predecessors of $X$? I can't see why it would make any difference which end you start at, but both your answer and the comment of Tomas seem to be saying that backwards is better, and I'd like to understand that.

Answer (score 2):

5 and there's not much more I can say, apart from state what they are: stay left all the way (LL), stay right all the way (RR), LR, RLL and RLR.